# How can I update mulitple records at once in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, update-attributes

I am developing a Ruby on Rails app. In my controller I need to update the table attributes multiple times. I've put this logic in the controller.

```
def index   
  if request.post?
    @user_new = Bookmark.new(params[:user_new])
    tags = @user_new.tags.split(",")
    i=0
    while i < tags.length
      @user_new.update_attributes(:title => @user_new.title, :url => @user_new.url, :tags => i)  
      i=i+1
    end

   @check = "hello"
  end   

 end
```

This iterates over the while loop until the tags array size is reached. And multiple times updating is done with different values inside the table.

This should yield updation of all the records. In a case if array size is 3, there should be 3 records inserted. But it is not happenning. Can anyone tell me how to insert mulitple records using array as the differentiation factor in each row?

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work:

```
@user_new = Bookmark.new(params[:user_new])
if @user_new.save!
  @user_new.tags.split(",").each do |tag|
    tag.update_attributes(:title => @user_new.title, :url => @user_new.url)  
  end
else
  < do something else >>
end
```

Or you could use .create instead.

**Follow the other post from @Thilo to index the tags.**

Also, if you run this with ! on update_attributes! do you see any errors.

You might have some validation errors. Try that and check the console / log.

Comment: sorry , it supposed to be  ":tags => tag[i]"  . That means every element inside the array is iterated and inserted.

Comment: Can you try with the bang (!) and see if you get anything and we can worry about that bit later? Do you have attr_accessible in your model?

Comment: i get nomethoderror if exceute this   @user_new.tags.split(",").each    do |tags|
      tags.update_attributes(:title => @user_new.title, :url => @user_new.url)  
      end      . I need to update the array values also how to do them?

Comment: @Thilo is correct - I'd not noticed you'd not saved the model. Try doing something like above edit.